# How do I run GIMP 2.10 from a command line in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, gimp

I installed flatpack GIMP 2.10 in a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM, and I'm trying to run it from a command line. (I'm hoping that error messages will tell me why my Python script won't load.) Unfortunately, the terminal says that the "gimp" command doesn't exist. I suspect that adding GIMP to the PATH variable might help, but how do I find the path? (If it helps, the Python plug-in folder is: /app/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins .)